# How to automate inpainting process from stable diffusion?

Tags: python, stable-diffusion, inpainting

Hello dear StackOverflow community,
I am currently working on a project with stable diffusion. In this project the clothes of a person in a photo should be exchanged with any other clothes.

If I do it manually (via stable diffsuion web ui) it works fine. But now I wonder (because I want to use the whole thing as a console application) if there is a possibility to automate the inpaint process. So that the clothes are already automatically detected.
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.